# How to avoid an immediate notification In android app if the time you set has already passed?

Tags: android

I wanted to send a local notification to user daily at 06.00 pm.
but the problem is that if user opens the app after 06.00 pm. the Notification is getting repeated.
how To solve this problem ?

Below is my Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();


            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 02);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 54);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            if(calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }



            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Please help me.

Comment: So , as per that answer . I just have to add following lines to solve the problem -                                                                                              if(calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

Comment: @MikeM. have implemented what you told, But now Notifications are stopped fully. They dont show even at specified time   . ( I have updated above code too )

Comment: `HOUR_OF_DAY` is on the 24-hour clock. Your `Calendar` is set for 2:54am.

Comment: Okay..I'll try again

Comment: Now thats working great...Thanks for help